# Soft Limits and Hard Limits in HortonWorks

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform, cloudera-cdh, ambari, cgroups

I am trying to figure out how to configure soft limits and hard limits for the memory subsystem (Cgroups) in Hortonworks. I was successful in configuring it in Cloudera. But, I haven't found anything as such in Horton Works.

Can anyone let me know, is there a way to configure at all, as I couldn't find anything related to this in any of the Hortonworks documentation?
If yes, How?

Thank you.

Comment: This might help you https://hortonworks.com/blog/apache-hadoop-yarn-in-hdp-2-2-isolation-of-cpu-resources-in-your-hadoop-yarn-clusters/

Comment: @BruceWayne I have gone through this article. It doesn't say anything much about the memory subsystem being mounted.